# Why does my Spring Boot 3 RestController with @GetMapping require header "content-length: 0" to be set?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Spring Boot 3 `@RestController` and `@GetMapping` responds with HTTP status code 400 "bad request", unless the HTTP request contains header "content-length: 0". I am using `spring-boot-starter-parent:3.0.2` and required libraries.

I wrote an integration test using Spring `RestTemplate` to call my service. The `RestTemplate` requests always contain "content-length: 0". This behaviour just occured to me, when I set up a JMeter test and received "bad request" responses. This is because JMeter does not include content-length in GET requests. HTTP 1.1 encourages this behaviour as the info is redundant. [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-content-length)

> A user agent SHOULD NOT send a Content-Length header field when the request message does not contain content and the method semantics do not anticipate such data.

To me it seems like an error with Spring Boot 3. But maybe I have misconfigured something? Can you think of something that triggers this problem?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/myService")
@Component
@Slf4j
class GetServlet {
  @GetMapping(value = "/greeting", produces = "text/plain")
  public ResponseEntity getGreeting() {
    log.debug("Sending greeting");
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello world!");
  }
}
```

Removing parameter "produces" did not change the service.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/myService")
@Component
@Slf4j
class GetServlet {
  @GetMapping(value = "/greeting")
  public ResponseEntity getGreeting() {
    log.debug("Sending greeting");
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("text/plain"))
            .body("Hello world!");
  }
}
```

Comment: what happen if remove "produce = "text/plain"? I think define produce and consume sometimes caused this issue.

Comment: Hey Amir, thank you for this 1st hint. It did not change behaviour of the service, though.

Comment: @Martin, it should be 0 for a GET request (because it doesn't have a body). For requests such as POST, the content-length represents the size of the http body payload.

Comment: My problem is that JMeter and Curl do not include content-length with GET requests. This is encouraged by HTTP 1.1. So my REST service receives a valid request, but responds with "bad request".

Comment: I just checked the official "gs-spring-boot" tutorial at Github to not have this problem. Now I have to inspect my additional dependencies on possible interferences, like Lombok  and spring-boot-starter-validation

Comment: Default behaviour of spring doesn't needs `Content-Length: 0`. So, you have a config or additional dependencies causing that behaviour.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out, we had a Filter implementation in our project that checked on content-length and threw "bad request" on it missing. So basically Spring Boot just did what we told it to. The filter was intented to improve a @PostMapping, but of course, it was enabled globally.